# How do I kill grelod the kind with out getting noticed ?? On Xbox 360

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I enter at night or when ever she is alone (invisible), I kill her with my bow (I turn invisible)-- and somehow Constance Michel notices this in her room with doors closed, and afterwards runs across the orphanage  telling me she yields and won't stop!
How can I kill Grelod the Kind without Constance Michel yelling terrified?

Comment: This is almost an exact duplicate of that question with some minor wording changes. There are no differences to the way Constance behaves on the 360 to the PC version.

Comment: IK THE ANSWER NOW , I just needed to complete the quest by telling the boy she was dead

Comment: And idk why mine looks the same

Comment: Most likely because you haven't exactly attempted to research this problem before asking. Don't worry! Our [How to Ask](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page provides a good starting point on what to do if you wish to ask!

Comment: Whoa whoa whoa this is not me

Comment: Even if you kill her secretly, Constance will still be fleeing until you wait a few days and she should reset.